# spark read csv with epoch timestamp

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark

I've a CSV file with the following schema and data example:

```
userId,movieId,tag,timestamp
28,63062,angelina jolie,1263047558
```

I have the following code to read this file.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val inputPath = "FileStore/tables/o8pa07nd1495067426592/tags.csv"

val customSchema = StructType(Array(
    StructField("userId", StringType, true),
    StructField("movieId", StringType, true),
    StructField("tag", StringType, true),
    StructField("timestamp", TimestampType, true)))

val df = spark.read
   .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
   .option("header", "true") // Use first line of all files as header
   .schema(customSchema)
   .load(inputPath)
```

I have the following code to select data from `dataframe`

```
df.select($"timestamp", $"tag").show(10)
```

However, it's failing with `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`

In `CustomSchema`, if I change the type from TimestampType to LongType it works fine. But, I want to read the column as Timestamp. How can I do that?

Here is the complete error log

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.sql.Date.valueOf(Date.java:143)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.DateTimeUtils$.stringToTime(DateTimeUtils.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVTypeCast$$anonfun$castTo$6.apply$mcJ$sp(CSVInferSchema.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVTypeCast$$anonfun$castTo$6.apply(CSVInferSchema.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVTypeCast$$anonfun$castTo$6.apply(CSVInferSchema.scala:283)
    at scala.util.Try.getOrElse(Try.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVTypeCast$.castTo(CSVInferSchema.scala:280)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVRelation$$anonfun$csvParser$3.apply(CSVRelation.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVRelation$$anonfun$csvParser$3.apply(CSVRelation.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat$$anonfun$buildReader$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(CSVFileFormat.scala:173)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat$$anonfun$buildReader$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(CSVFileFormat.scala:172)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anonfun$prepareNextFile$1.apply(FileScanRDD.scala:235)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anonfun$prepareNextFile$1.apply(FileScanRDD.scala:217)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1442)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1430)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1429)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1429)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:803)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:803)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:803)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1657)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1612)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1601)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:628)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1937)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1950)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1963)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:333)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$7.apply(Dataset.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$7.apply(Dataset.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$60.apply(Dataset.scala:2791)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withFileAccessAudit(SQLExecution.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:2790)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:643)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:602)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.sql.Date.valueOf(Date.java:143)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.DateTimeUtils$.stringToTime(DateTimeUtils.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVTypeCast$$anonfun$castTo$6.apply$mcJ$sp(CSVInferSchema.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVTypeCast$$anonfun$castTo$6.apply(CSVInferSchema.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVTypeCast$$anonfun$castTo$6.apply(CSVInferSchema.scala:283)
    at scala.util.Try.getOrElse(Try.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVTypeCast$.castTo(CSVInferSchema.scala:280)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVRelation$$anonfun$csvParser$3.apply(CSVRelation.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVRelation$$anonfun$csvParser$3.apply(CSVRelation.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat$$anonfun$buildReader$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(CSVFileFormat.scala:173)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat$$anonfun$buildReader$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(CSVFileFormat.scala:172)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anonfun$prepareNextFile$1.apply(FileScanRDD.scala:235)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anonfun$prepareNextFile$1.apply(FileScanRDD.scala:217)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Not an answer to your query but, I assume you would convert it to human readable date later on. Why not read it as long and then later on map it to Date ?

Comment: @rpanda did you get any solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

`java.sql.Date.valueOf` will throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if the date given is not in the JDBC date escape format (yyyy-mm-dd). From your input example, it looks like your data is in unix epoch format.

One way to solve this would be to read the field as a Long and then do the conversion to timestamp yourself. The `from_unixtime` in the `org.apache.spark.sql.function` packet is one alternative, or you could create an UDF. I would recommend using the `from_unixtime` method:

```
df.withColumn("time", from_unixtime($"timestamp"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If your timestamp contains milliseconds:

```
df.withColumn("time_with_ms", ($"timestamp"/1000).cast(TimestampType))
```